# How to get input from user and pass it to an interactive command line program triggered by subprocess call in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a command-line program which when triggered provides a list of options and prompts the user to select an option to continue.

Now I have launched the command line program using subprocess call, now the command line program prompts for the value, how do I pass the value from user to the command line program via subprocess call?

Comment: The best solution is going to depend at least in part on what the cli options are for the sub program you want to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) just waits for the process to finish and gives return code, no way to interact with it. if you instead use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that gives you the ability to communicate with the subprocess while it is running via `stdin` and `stdout`

```
import subprocess, sys
program = subprocess.Popen("python3", 
                           # give us a pipes to coommunicate
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
data = input("input to subprocess")
[out,err] = program.communicate((data+"\n").encode())

print(out.decode())

print(err.decode(), file=sys.stderr)
```

Doing a bit of input then some output then more input can get messy though since there reading from stdout is blocking so determining when the output has stopped for more input is tricky.

Comment: Is there any way to check whether the subprocess is actually waiting with stdin open for input from the user?

Comment: no, unfortunately there isn't a way a program can communicate that is is blocking on additional data in stdin, at least not a standard one that all programs just do inherently.  There are solutions like reading the stdout in a thread and writing it to a queue so you can empty the queue every time you push input and I know there are more complicated solutions using `select` module to see if `sys.stdin` has new data or `program.stdout` has data and deal with them nearly asynchronously, but usually the specifics are application specific so it's hard to write generic answer without knowing more.